# Setting element to draggable with jsPlumb makes it disappear

Tags: javascript, xhtml, draggable, jsplumb

I am trying to create flow-charts using jsPlumb. I am using it on xhtml file and considering to use it with a backing bean later on. I was messing with preview of drag and drop demo on their website and mutated it a little according to my need. It basically removes End Points(EP) from a chart and makes them non-draggable. My code is working on html file, however, whenever I use it with xhtml charts disappear on setting their draggable on false. It doesn't do that if I use true. Anyway, my question is why it's behaving in such way and how can I solve it?

Here's some parts of my code:

```
function preview() {

    var windows = $(".shape");
    var x;
    for ( var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        x = windows[i].getElementsByClassName("ep");
        windows[i].removeChild(x[0]);
        jsPlumb.setDraggable(windows[i], false); // makes charts disappear
    }

    jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
}
```

Again, exact code works on html file.
xhtml file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/XsZe4Wne) and javascript file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ccf11a1v)

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link.
http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/home

section: 
application/xhtml+xml

If you're serving application/xhtml+xml then you need to include the VML namespace in the html element:

http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

Don't forget that in IE<9, XHTML is not supported.

Comment: We've solved this problem. It was caused by a missing background image of library but we thought library was doing some weird stuff in background. We, somehow, missed it :)

Comment: I did not understand, what was going wrong with the image ?

Comment: The image itself (the actual resource) was missing. I assumed  it's there and when I see the ill behavior, I assumed there is something wrong with the code itself.